# Opencv: detecting brightest line on FFT

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I have a fast fourier transform of my image like this:

[image]

I want to use edge detection and hough transform to get this bright horizontal line (I'm measuring the angle of rotation of the image). But Canny operator doesn't work well, because there are such small color variations. How can I detect that line?

I produce the FFT like this:

```py
dft = cv2.dft(frame, flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
spectrum = 20 * np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft[:, :, 0], dft[:, :, 1]))
# Converting to uint8 for Canny and HoughLinesP
spectrum = spectrum / np.max(spectrum) * 255
spectrum = spectrum.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray and invert
- Apply adaptive thresholding and invert
- Apply morphology to clean the threshold and fill out the line
- Apply Canny edge detection
- Apply Hough line detection
- Draw the largest line
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('fft.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray

# threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 3)
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply close to connect the white areas
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((1,9), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(morph, 150, 200)

# get hough lines
result = img.copy()
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50)
# Draw line on the image
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(result, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save resulting images
cv2.imwrite('fft_thresh.jpg',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('fft_morph.jpg',morph)
cv2.imwrite('fft_edges.jpg',edges)
cv2.imwrite('fft_line.jpg',result)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Edge image:

[image]

Resulting Hough line drawn on input image:

[image]